# Kubo formula derivation

Tags: electricity, condensed-matter, conductors, quantum-transport

In the derivation of the Kubo formula for conductivty we write the total hamiltonian as  $$H_{\text{tot}}=H_0+H_{\text{ext}}$$ where $$H_{\text{tot}}=H(A_0+A_{\text{ext}}),$$ $$H_0=H(A_0)$$ and $$H_{\text{ext}}=H(A_0+A_{\text{ext}})-H(A_0)$$ where$$H(A)=\frac{1}{2m}(p-qA)^2+V$$ thus we have up to linear order $$H_{\text{tot}}=\frac{1}{2m}(p-qA_0)^2+V-q\int drJA_{\text{ext}}$$ here first two terms are describes the equilibrium state and the last term describes the term responsible for electrical current flow. We also have $$E=-\partial_tA_{\text{ext}}$$.

Here the confusing part for me is, I don't get the difference between $A_0$ and $A_{\text{ext}}$ the system is under a electromagnetic potenial but only some portion of it induces current namely $A_{\text{ext}}$ on the other hand $A_0$ does not induce a current, this I don't understand. In other word how we choose what is $A_0$  what is $A_{\text{ext}}$.

Comment: Yes of course the part $A_0$ generates current, but the current itself is separated into two parts. Now, without magnetic field, one has the current $j\propto \partial_{t} E$, with $E$ the electric field, and if in addition $E\propto \partial_{t}A$ with $A$ the vector potential, then a static $A_0$ would not produce current. I feel it's a working hypothesis for the problem you have.

Comment: @FraSChelle $\partial_tE$ is proportional to displacement current it is not proportional to electrict current. electric fiels is proprtional to current.

Comment: Ok, and what does it change as long as $A_0$ is time independent ? Using the definition of current or a constitutive relation makes no difference as far as I can see.